# RadomForest Tree structure is too vast for visual inspection, how to condense?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, graphviz, decision-tree

I trained a BalancedRandomForest for a classification problem and now I want to plot one tree. However, when using `export_graphviz` to do so, the tree output is too vast and I do not want all trees to display, only 1 random one. How can I achieve this?

```
#train balanced random forest
brf = BalancedRandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, random_state=0)
#fit model
brf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_brf = brf.predict(X_test)

# Extract single tree
estimator = brf.estimators_[1]
# Export as dot file
export_graphviz(estimator, 
                out_file='tree.dot', 
                feature_names = ['feature_1','feature_2','feature_3'],
                class_names =['fraud','no_fraud'],
                rounded = True, 
                proportion = False, 
                precision = 2, 
                filled = True)

# Convert to png using system command (requires Graphviz)
from subprocess import call
call(['dot', '-Tpng', 'tree.dot', '-o', 'tree.png', '-Gdpi=100'])

# Display in jupyter notebook
from IPython.display import Image
Image(filename = 'tree.png')
```

The output I get is this vast tree structure (this screenshot does not even display the entire tree, its even bigger!): [image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `max_depth` into the model such as:

```
brf = BalancedRandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50, random_state=0, max_depth = 2)
```

Comment: `max_depth` affects the depth shown, not the number of trees, which was already 1 in your code. Your title is misleading, I kindly suggest editing it accordingly.

Comment: @desertnaut, so it was a matter of adding max_depth and n_estimators.